# Inverting one-to-many mapping using dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
lst = [{'272': '4', '273': '4', '274': '4', '275': '5'}]
dct = {}

for k, v in lst[0].items():
    if dct.get(v) is None:
        dct.update({v: [k]})
    else:
        dct[v].append(k)
```

Output:

```
{'4': ['272', '273', '274'], '5': ['275']}
```

I can also write a nested comprehension:

```
dct = {v: [k for (k, v1) in lst[0].items() if v1 == v]
          for (k, v) in lst[0].items()}
```

Output is same:

```
{'4': ['272', '273', '274'], '5': ['275']}**
```

But can we try to acheive the same result by using a single `for` loop in the dict comprehension?

Comment: Do you want to sort the list? I dont see what your problem is.

Comment: Ah so you want to make a O(n) converter instead of a O(n^2)?

Comment: In the dict comprehension there is a nested loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't quite do the same thing in a dict comprehension in one step. You're effectively inverting the dictionary, but since you don't have a 1-to-1 mapping in the original, you need to aggregate repeated keys for each value.

The list in the question is a red herring. I am going to use

```
d = {'272': '4', '273': '4', '274': '4', '275': '5'}
```

There are a couple of approaches you can take. The sane one is to keep a loop, but simplify it slightly. For example, you could use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), which is like a regular `dict`, except it lets you automatically set missing keys with empty values:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in d.items():
    result[v].append(k)
```

You can write a comprehension for this if you use a couple of standard library functions though. One way is to use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), but that requires you to apply [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) first:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

result = {k: list(map(itemgetter(0), vs))
              for k, vs in groupby(sorted(d.items(),
                                          key=itemgetter(1, 0)),
                                   itemgetter(1))}
```

[`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) works like `lambda x: x[0]` or so here, but faster and more efficiently.

With the second solution, note that the time complexity went from O(n) to O(n log n) because of the sort, and you sacrifice a lot of legibility just to have a "one-liner".

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode. Good call. I forgot about ordering.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode. Updated. It's a mess either way

Answer (score 1):

A hack with a temporary helper dictionary:

```
dct = {v: h.setdefault(v, [k])
       for h in [{}]
       for k, v in lst[0].items()
       if v not in h or h[v].append(k)}
```